# How Can I Looping For with items inside

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js

***this is my code for loop***

```
<tr v-for="(items, index) in cart" :key="items.id">
   <td>{{ index + 1 }}</td>
   <td v-for="(item, index) in items.cart_items" :key="index"><img :src="item.product.image" alt="" srcset="" class="img-fluid" width="200px"></td>
</tr>
```

i wanna loop **cart_items** inside the **cart**.. **cart_items** contain **product**.. and i wanna call inside td like this..

```
<tr v-for="(items, index) in cart" :key="items.id">
    <td>{{ index + 1 }}</td>
    <td v-for="(item, index) in items.cart_items" :key="index"><img :src="item.product.image" alt="" srcset="" class="img-fluid" width="200px"></td>
    <td v-for="(item, index) in items.cart_items" :key="index">{{ item.product.name }}</td>
</tr>
```

but im confused if i call product.name in the new td.. because vue show warning like this

***[Vue warn]: Duplicate keys detected: '0'. This may cause an update error.***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<tr v-for="(items, index) in cart" :key="items.id">
    <td>{{ index + 1 }}</td>
    <td v-for="(item, index) in items.cart_items" :key="index"><img :src="item.product.image" alt="" srcset="" class="img-fluid" width="200px"></td>
    <td v-for="(item, index) in items.cart_items" :key="index">{{ item.product.name }}</td>
</tr>
```

In the above code, you are using the same `index` as a key for two `td` elements which is not a good approach.

Key-value should be always unique for each element rendered.